# How to add custom with static cell in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using UITablViewContoller with static cells. I have designed static cells in storyboard itself. I need to add dynamic listing in one of the cell. I am trying to use custom cell for the same. Bt I am not getting result.
I am using below code in my UITableViewController.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if(indexPath.row == 7){
    CommentTableViewCell *cell = (CommentTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentTableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;
}
else{
    // This part causes the problem. Not sure what to pass here. Without else part it throws error.
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    return cell;
    }
 }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 9; // number of static cells in storyboard
}
```

Comment: Did you override/implement the number of rows in section method? this one -> `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

Comment: @Vinodh are you able to use custom cell with static cell ??

Comment: @mownier i have added code for tableView:numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I think your cell is created . But You have nothing put on your cell .
In else section try to add 

cell.textLabel.text = @"HOME";
@luckyShubhra

Comment: Is `CommentTableViewCell` the one in the Interface Builder?

Comment: It is static cell so you can't dynamic it. If you want dynamic but static content, then go for dynamic cells but static datasource.